# Deprecated conversion from string const. to wchar_t*

Tags: c++, deprecated, wchar-t

Hello I have a pump class that requires using a member variable that is a pointer to a wchar_t array containing the port address ie: "com9".

The problem is that when I initialise this variable in the constructor my compiler flags up a depreciated conversion warning.

```
pump::pump(){
   this->portNumber = L"com9";}
```

This works fine but the warning every time I compile is anoying and makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong.

I tried creating an array and then setting the member variable like this:

```
pump::pump(){
   wchar_t port[] = L"com9";
   this->portNumber = port;}
```

But for some reason this makes my portNumber point at 'F'.

Clearly another conceptual problem on my part.

Thanks for help with my noobish questions.

EDIT:

As request the definition of portNumber was:

```
    class pump
{
private:
   wchar_t* portNumber;
}
```

Thanks to answers it has now been changed to:

```
    class pump
{
private:
   const wchar_t* portNumber;
}
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `pump::portNumber` please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `portNumber` is a `wchar_t*`, it should be a `const wchar_t*`.

String literals are immutable, so the elements are `const`. There exists a deprecated conversion from string literal to non-const pointer, but that's dangerous. Make the change so you're keeping type safety and not using the unsafe conversion.

The second one fails because you point to the contents of a local variable. When the constructor finishes, the variable goes away and you're pointing at an invalid location. Using it results in undefined behavior.

Lastly, use an initialization list:

```
pump::pump() :
portNumber(L"com9")
{}
```

The initialization list is to initialize, the constructor is to finish construction. (Also, `this->` is ugly to almost all C++ people; it's not nice and redundant.)

Comment: What if the definition of portNumber cannot be changed because it is part of 3rd party code? I seem unable to make the warning go away whatever I try, as I don't know how to tell the compiler not to make a literal.

Comment: @MikeVersteeg: If you can't change the code, your only option is to try and suppress the warning. AFAIK, most compilers have ways of disabling and reenabling warnings with a pragma - you can disable warnings prior to `#include`, and reenable after.

Comment: Thanks, but that is no longer possible with C++11 compilers (at least not mine). I did manage to work around the issue by dynamically creating a string and use that. Learned a lot from this post.

Answer (score 2):

Use `const wchar_t*` to point at a literal.

The reason the conversion exists is because it has been valid from early versions of C to assign a string literal to a non-const pointer[*]. The reason it's deprecated is that it's invalid to modify a literal, and it's risky to use a non-const pointer to refer to something that must not be modified.

[*] C didn't originally have `const`. When `const` was added, clearly it should apply to string literals, but there was already code out there, written before `const` existed, that would break if suddenly you had to sprinkle `const` everywhere. We're still paying today for that breaking change to the language. Since it's C++ you're using, it wasn't even a breaking change to this language.

Comment: One of the things that ruin most C++ is the C backwards compatibility even in the most idiotic choices (C standard library included).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `portNumber` is a `wchar_t *` (non-const), correct? If so:

- the first one is wrong, because string literals are read-only (they are const pointers to an array of char *usually* stored in the string table of the executable, which is mapped in memory somewhere, often in a readonly page).
  The ugly, implicit conversion to non-const `char`s/`wchar_t`s was approved, IIRC, to achieve compatibility with old code written when `const` didn't even existed; sadly, it let a lot of morons which do not know what *const correctness* means get away with writing code that asks non-const pointers even when const pointers would be the right choice.
- The second one is wrong because you're making `portNumber` point to a variable allocated on the stack, which is deleted when the constructor returns. After the constructor returns, the pointer stored in `portNumber` points to random garbage.

The correct approach is to declare `portNumber` as `const wchar_t *` if it doesn't need to be modified. If, instead, it *does* need to be modified during the lifetime of the class, usually the best approach is to avoid C-style strings at all and just throw in a `std::wstring`, that will take care of all the bookkeeping associated with the string.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In this case the port number may be changed dynamically (from a drop down menu) because the pump may not always be on com9. The reason I'm using a wchar_t pointer at all is because it is required as an argument in the CreateFile() function. I will see if it accepts a std::wstring.

Comment: It doesn't accept a wstring, but wstring (as any string built on std::basic_string) provides the c_str() method that returns a const wchar_t * to let C functions access its content.